# Textures in unwanted area using UV map

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: uv map used for displacement]

[image: Side view]

[image: Shown from the foot of the bed]

I am stumped. I have added this texture by editing the UV map and adding it through a displacement node. I made sure that the texture was nowhere near the seams so I didn't go into another area. I usually delete the unused edges in the UV map, I just started redoing this, this morning. Are there settings in the UV mapping that I am missing? How can I correct this?

Comment: what is the texture looking like? Screenshot of uv map over texture would help, also, select only affected faces (not whole mesh) and go to uv and make a screen there, part of your uv (in that area) must have lost it original scale

Comment: The top image is the texture over the uv map. Are you saying to select only the area that the texture will go into and export that as the uv map? I am trying different ways to unwrap the mesh. This time the uv map looks completely different. I'll let you know or delete this question if it works.

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: no, I meant that you will select specific faces and you will go to uv editing tab and make a screenshot of your blender so that we can see more information, or as @moonboots says, share your file with blenderexchange or pasteall

Comment: I reset the uv map and redid it. That corrected the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.